# PostgreSQL crosstab() alternative with CASE and aggregates

Tags: postgresql, join, case, aggregate, crosstab

I want to create a pivot table view showing month on month sum of bookings for every `travel_mode`.

Table `bookings`:

```
  timestamp
, bookings
, provider_id
```

Table `providers`:

```
  provider_id
, travel_mode
```

Pivot table function and crosstab functions are not to be used to do this. So I am trying to use JOIN and CASE. Following is the query:

```
  SELECT b.month, 
  (CASE WHEN p.travel_mode=train then b.amount end)train,
  (CASE WHEN p.travel_mode=bus then b.amount end)bus, 
  (CASE WHEN p.travel_mode=air then b.amount end)air
  FROM 
  (SELECT  to_char(date_,month) as month, travel_mode, sum(bookings) as amount
  from bookings as b
  join providers as p
  on b.provider_id=p.provider_id
  group by b.month, p.travel_mode)
  group by b.month;
```

However I am getting an error which says:

> ```
> subquery in FROM must have an alias LINE 6:
> ```

And when I add an alias it throws an error saying:

> ```
> column p.travel_mode must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function 
> LINE 2:
> ```

The final result should be something like this

```
Month       Air             Bus            Train  
01          Amount(air)     Amount(Bus)    Amount(train)
```

I have a feeling it is a minor error somewhere but I am unable to figure it out at all.

P.S. I had to remove all quotations in the question as it was not allowing me to post this. But those are being taken care of in the actual query.

Comment: You can (and should) post all your quotations. SO certainly allows that. You should always add the actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple problems. The missing table alias is just one of them. This query should work:

```
SELECT month
     , sum(CASE WHEN travel_mode = 'train' THEN amount END) AS train
     , sum(CASE WHEN travel_mode = 'bus'   THEN amount END) AS bus
     , sum(CASE WHEN travel_mode = 'air'   THEN amount END) AS air
FROM  (
   SELECT to_char(timestamp, 'MM') AS month, travel_mode, sum(bookings) AS amount
   FROM   bookings  b
   JOIN   providers p USING (provider_id)
   GROUP  BY month, p.travel_mode
   ) sub
GROUP  BY month;
```

- Missing single quotes for string literals. (You seem to have removed those being under the wrong impression you couldn't post quotations.)
- Missing table alias for the subquery - just like the 1st error message says.
- In the outer query, table names (or aliases) of underlying tables in the subquery are not visible. Only the table alias of the subquery is. Since there is only *one* subquery, you don't need table-qualification at all there.
- `month` is an output column name (not in the underlying table), so the table qualification `b.month` was wrong, too.
- You seem to want 2-digit numbers for months. Use the [template pattern 'MM'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) instead of 'month' with `to_char()`.
- The aggregation in the outer query does not work like you had it - just like your 2nd error message says. You have to wrap the outer `CASE` expression in a aggregate function. You might as well use `min()` or `max()` in this case, because there are never more than one rows after the subquery.
- Still unclear where `date_` is coming from? You mean `timestamp`? (which is not a good identifier).

But you don't need the subquery to begin with and can simplify to:

```
SELECT to_char(timestamp, 'MM') AS month
     , sum(CASE WHEN p.travel_mode = 'train' THEN b.bookings END) AS train
     , sum(CASE WHEN p.travel_mode = 'bus'   THEN b.bookings END) AS bus
     , sum(CASE WHEN p.travel_mode = 'air'   THEN b.bookings END) AS air
FROM   bookings  b
JOIN   providers p USING (provider_id)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

For best performance you should still use `crosstab()`, though:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: The 1st query did not work. This is the error it is throwing
ERROR: column b.month does not exist LINE 9: GROUP BY b.month, p.travel_mode ^

Comment: @justanothernewbie: That's fixed by now. Try the latest version. (`month` is an output column name, so the table-qualification was wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to name the subquery as the error message says:

```
SELECT b.month, 
(CASE WHEN p.travel_mode=train then b.amount end)train,
(CASE WHEN p.travel_mode=bus then b.amount end)bus, 
(CASE WHEN p.travel_mode=air then b.amount end)air
FROM 
(SELECT  to_char(date_,month) as month, travel_mode, sum(bookings) as amount
from bookings as b
join providers as p
on b.provider_id=p.provider_id
group by b.month, p.travel_mode)
**as foo** group by b.month;
```

Remove the stars to make it work.